# Fedora bash program not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, fedora

I am trying to just run a simple bash command but i'm not sure what i'm misssing

```
#!/bin/bash
$person = Craig Baiey
echo $person
echo '$person'
echo "$person"
```

everytime I run it i get an error
line 2: =: command not found

$person

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it did thank you. Sorry haven't been on in a few days

Answer (score 4):

Space is the problem around `=`. It should be:

```
person="Craig Baiey"
```

- You don't assign into variable with `$` in name.
- And quotes are also required there.

btw this line won't print the variable's value:

```
echo '$person'
```

As shell won't expand it due to presence of single quotes. It will instead literal `$person`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ before person on line 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
person="Craig Baiey"
echo $person
```

Comment: Can't have the space either - `person="..."`

Comment: If the goal is to demonstrate good practices, `echo "$person"` is the safer option -- if someone's name should be printed with two spaces between the first and last, string-splitting and letting echo reassemble it wrong is hardly good etiquette, never mind what happens to `Bobby (aka * ) Wildcard`.